# Can I disable auto import and import recommendations for deprecated components?

Tags: visual-studio-code, deprecated

Is there a way to set a given React component as `@deprecated` so that it will not show up in the auto-import list?

For example, I currently have 3 different iterations of a given component with the exact same name. Two of these are deprecated and I want them to no longer be used, but VSCode suggests importing these still.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this coming in v1.49:

> #### @deprecated tag support for JavaScript and TypeScript

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use `getMode()` instead.
 */
export function mode() { ... }
```

> VS Code renders IntelliSense suggestions for deprecated properties
> with a strike through (see the `show` and `hide` suggestions below for
> example):
>
> To help you detect usage of deprecated API in your codebase, VS Code
> will also add a strike through to any references to deprecated apis:
>
> Disable these strike throughs by setting `"editor.showDeprecated": false`.

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#deprecated-tag-support-for-javascript-and-typescript

---

It isn't component-level deprecation and they'll still be listed in intellisense, but at least the marked `export` functions will be pretty clearly marked with strike throughs.